# Basicity af N containing aromatic species

Tags: acid-base

[image: N containing aromatic bases]

Hello friends, I got struck in this interesting question on basicity. I am able to get different answers applying different methods.
In general, for these compounds we have to see the lone pair denoting tendency by the nitrogen.
I was able to conclude that **IV** is most basic. And **II** is greater than **I**. Now the problem is between **I** and **III**. Whether to consider the -I effect of $\ce{N}$ or $\ce{Ph}$ more effective? And, is -I the correct way to compare among both of these?
I even draw the resonating structures but was unable to conclude anything from there. Please help as to how to proceed.

Comment: (This might be cheating but will help any answerers). The pKa' values (pKa of conjugate acid) of pyrimidine (**I**) and quinoline (**III**) are 1.10 and 4.85 respectively. (Source: Wikipedia pages). This suggests **III** is more basic as it attacks $\ce{H+}$ at a lower $[\ce{H+}]$ concentration.

Comment: Dupe of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50303/why-is-pyrimidine-less-basic-than-pyridine https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92375/why-is-quinoline-less-basic-than-pyridine

Comment: @Mithoron unfortunately, a vs b and a vs c together don’t make duplicates of b vs c. That said, I am of the opinion that there is no way to answer this with beyond stating that, solely based on empirical evidence and experience, an extra nitrogen in the ring is more electron-withdrawing than a fused benzene ring. The proof is in the pKa values.

Comment: @orthocresol So I voted for too broad, but q. was kicked from queue because of edit that only corrected spelling...